# sklearn classification runtime

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a classification algorithm on a dataset, but I'm having problems getting certain iterations that use sklearn's PCA module to run.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

train = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('testData.csv')
target = train['is_exciting']
test.drop(['is_exciting'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

np.shape(train)

>>>(619326, 62)

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
```

if I feed in just the raw training data to my classifier, the runtime is about 20 minutes:

```
model.fit(train, target)
```

However, when I run another iteration where I first transformed my data using PCA, it didn't complete running in 3 hours. (I eventually killed it.)

```
pca = PCA(n_components=10)
x = pca.fit_transform(train)

print np.shape(x)

>>>(619326L, 10L)

model.fit(x, target)
```

What gives?  With 52 less variables I thought the PCA version would complete much quicker, but it doesn't seem to want to run at all!  Does it have to do with passing a numpy array vs a pandas dataframe?  My dataframe either has 1,0 flags (ints) or z score values (floats I believe).  I'm a bit stumped here - any help would be welcome!

Comment: Theoretically, should work. Have you tried running it on smaller subset of your data? This might give you a hint. Probably, something went wrong during PCA.

Comment: I have - I ran it on a 20 * 5 subsection of the data and that worked, but the full dataset takes forever.  If 10 is a bad number for the PCA features, would that matter?  I just can't understand why it would be so slow when it's just an array of floats.

Comment: can you convert train into a numpy array before passing it to the RandomForestClassifier or PCA? Pandas Dataframes are not officially supported as input and weird stuff could happen.

Comment: Are you using scikit-learn 0.15 (released yesterday)? The random forests got a massive performance boost in that version.

Comment: (Just a hunch) PCA doesn't just remove dimensions, it reorients the axes of the data. This means that the tree learning algorithm will find different, and perhaps more, candidate split points while growing its trees. I can imagine this happening esp. when your original data contained integer feature values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was not using the 0.15 release, I may now though :)  Looking at the data with 10 features, the majority of the datapoints seemed to have been set very small (I didn't see a single one not written in scientific notation).  With 7 features, the PCA features had much more variation.  Perhaps the small range in the data made it more difficult for the tree to split.

Answer (score 0):

So the best I could do was to reduce the number of features the PCA dataset was running.  At 7 features it ran relatively quickly, but as soon as I put in 10 features I never got it to complete, I'm not sure if it has to do with the data being developed, but I just ended up going with 7, and didn't see any adverse results in my output.